# Perl mark sub as Public or Private

Tags: perl, attributes

In Perl there is no public or private access for methods/subs. So I need to mark some subs as web call safe as a simple logic so in a simple check if that sub/function is marked as public then a direct web browser call to that action of the same name as the function is processed otherwise it is declined.

example:

```
sub Register : public {
 ...... This should be web browser call allowed
}

sub check_login {
  ... this by default should be private and not allowed to browser.
}
```

I have read some about different modules like  attributes () and moose or moo.

What is the best way to accomplish this. All I need is to check if some subs have marked as public or not, default will be private.

Comment: What did you try? The docs are [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/attributes.html)

Comment: Moose and similar do not add a protection mechanism.

Comment: Why not just use [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst)?

Comment: Catalyst is a very heavy package, hundreds of modules loaded for a single line application, I prefer to use my Owen frameworks to my specific needs.

Comment: I tried this:
`
use attributes ();
use Scalar::Util qw( refaddr );

my %attrs; # package variable to store attribute lists by coderef address

sub MODIFY_CODE_ATTRIBUTES {
    my ($package, $subref, @attrs) = @_;
    $attrs{ refaddr $subref } = \@attrs;
    return;
}

sub FETCH_CODE_ATTRIBUTES {
    my ($package, $subref) = @_;
    my $attrs = $attrs{ refaddr $subref };
    return @$attrs;
}

sub foo_bar : Public Global : Piv:Pal:Hal{
print "foo\n";
}

my @attr = attributes::get(\&foo_bar);
print "attributes: \n", join (",", @attr), "\n";`

Comment: That's not readable, and you didn't say what problem is has.

Comment: @ikegami yes I do not know how to format the code in comments, I did not say it has a problem, my question is what is the best logic/practice to do it.

Comment: You can't include line breaks in comments. If you need to add information to your question, add it to your question.

Comment: Are you saying you're looking for something that might be better than attributes? By what criteria do you want to judge which one is best?

Comment: Yes I read some where that attributes and those like it are heavy and consumes time so I am looking for the fastest and simplest and may be the more reliable logic.

Comment: If Catalyst is too heavy for you, there are other lightweight web frameworks available these days, such as Dancer (http://perldancer.org/) and Mojolicious (http://mojolicio.us/).

Comment: I don't see why they would add any time at all to calls. Why would calling a sub check its attributes? (If you don't tag me, I don't get notified of your comments since it's not my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sub::Talisman](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub%3a%3aTalisman) might be what you're looking for.

```
package MyPackage;

use Sub::Talisman qw( Public Private Shiny Author );

sub foo :Public :Author("Bob") {
   ...;
}

sub bar :Private :Shiny :Author("Bob") {
   ...;
}

# Find out if "bar" is private?
my $is_private = grep {
   $_ eq 'MyPackage::Private';
} Sub::Talisman->get_attributes(\&bar);

print "Is bar private? ", ($is_private ? 'YES' : 'NO'), "\n";

# Find out who wrote "foo"?
my ($author) = @{
   Sub::Talisman->get_attribute_parameters(\&bar, 'MyPackage::Author')
};

print "Who wrote foo? ", $author, "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

A common approach is to name the subroutines that you want to be private with a leading underscore.

```
sub foo_public {
}

sub _bar_private {
}
```

Comment: Yes good inside packages but I never liked those underscores, for me looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

[Sub::Private](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub%3a%3aPrivate) uses the syntax you want, though I don't have firsthand experience with the module. In perl, the convention is that private methods begin with an underscore and public ones don't. Public/private access, however, is not enforced.

Comment: +1 for the module as it leads me to another module Attribute::Protected which I am studying now even it seems very old but may be what I want.